# Snakemake create wildcards

Tags: python, snakemake

I have an input file like below. When I create wildcards, I get an error that the files are not found, because they have specific combinations.

```
bob_78/clip/bob_78.hjckl87.dup.srt.bam
bob_79/clip/bob_79.hjckl87.dup.srt.bam
bob_80/clip/bob_80.hjpolxf.dup.srt.bam
bob_81/clip/bob_81.hjpolxf.dup.srt.bam
bob_82/clip/bob_82.hgfhj29.dup.srt.bam
```

How to create a wildcards for these files?

```
SAMPLE=["bob_78","bob_79","bob_80","bob_81","bob_82"]
PREFIX=["hjckl87","hjpolxf","hgfhj29"]

rule all:
    expand("OUTDIR/{sample}.{prefix}.clipped.txt", sample=SAMPLES, prefix=PREFIX)

rule xxx:
    input:
        ins="{sample}/clip/{sample}.{prefix}.dup.srt.bam"
    output:
        outfile="OUTDIR/{sample}.{prefix}.clipped.txt"
    shell:
        """
        some code
        """
```

Comment: your `SAMPLE` and `PREFIX` don't match. Expand takes the product between the two, and that is not the case here. Easiest is to write down all the files you expect in the end by hand

Comment: what do you mean? could you please make an example? thank you

Comment: The answer or @Dmitiy-Kusminov is the way to go here, it will give you what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may `zip` two lists, but as @Maarten-vd-Sande said, the lists have to match:

```py
SAMPLE=["bob_78", "bob_79", "bob_80", "bob_81", "bob_82"]
PREFIX=["hjckl87", "hjckl87", "hjpolxf", "hjpolxf", "hgfhj29"]

rule all:
    expand("OUTDIR/{sample}.{prefix}.clipped.txt", zip, sample=SAMPLES, prefix=PREFIX)
```